# decipher.final(): Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data

Tags: javascript, node.js, aes

I have the following code:

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

const algorithm = "aes-256-gcm"; 
const message = "This is a secret message";
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);
const sKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, sKey, iv);
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, sKey, iv)

let encryptedData = cipher.update(message, "utf-8", "hex");
encryptedData += cipher.final("hex");

let decData = decipher.update(encryptedData, "hex", "utf-8");
decData += decipher.final("utf-8");

console.log("Encrypted message: " + encryptedData);
console.log("Decrypted message: ", decData)
```

When I run it, I receive the following exception:

```
node:internal/crypto/cipher:193
  const ret = this[kHandle].final();
                            ^

Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data
    at Decipheriv.final (node:internal/crypto/cipher:193:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([...]/crypto-test.js:15:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Error is thrown when calling `decipher.final()`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using an authenticated cipher (which `aes-256-gcm` is), you'll need the auth tag from the cipher; otherwise `Decipher.final()` will throw (as you can see) since the auth tag it has (or in this case, doesn't) doesn't match what it thinks the deciphered text's auth tag is.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const algorithm = 'aes-256-gcm';
const message = 'This is a secret message';
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);
const sKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, sKey, iv);

let encryptedData = cipher.update(message, 'utf-8', 'hex');
encryptedData += cipher.final('hex');

const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag().toString("hex");  // <- new
console.log({authTag, encryptedData});  // for debugging

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, sKey, iv);
decipher.setAuthTag(Buffer.from(authTag, 'hex'));  // <- new
let decData = decipher.update(encryptedData, 'hex', 'utf-8');
decData += decipher.final('utf-8');
console.log('Decrypted message: ', decData)
```